# Additional classes `undefined` after saving post in Gutenberg

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

**The problem:** whenever I type something in **Advanced->Additional Classes** in Gutenberg editor and save the page/post and refresh, those classes disappear. I logged **props.className** in `edit` function. It logs the value as expected when I type the class name in the **Advanced->Additional Classes** field. The problem occurs when I save the post after inputting the class name and refresh the page. I followed the exact same method in other blocks I created and they work just fine.

**The Code:**

```js
    edit: (props) => {
        const {attributes, setAttributes} = props;
        const headingBgOverlay = Util.getBgOverlay(attributes, 'heading');
        const bodyBgOverlay = Util.getBgOverlay(attributes, 'body');

        useEffect(() => {
            setAttributes({blockId: Util.guidGenerator()});
        }, []);

        useEffect(() => {
            console.log(props)
            console.log(props.className)
            console.log(attributes.className)
            setAttributes({headingBgOverlay});
            setAttributes({bodyBgOverlay});
        }, [attributes]);
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Fragment>
                    <style>
                        {listIconCss(attributes)}
                    </style>
                    <div className={"atbs atbs-pricing-table " + props.className}
                         id={'atbs-pricing-table-' + attributes.blockId}>
                        <div className="plan"
                             style={{...planCss(attributes)}}>
                            <div className="head" style={{...titleCss(attributes)}}>
                                <RichText style={{...titleTypographyCss(attributes)}} tagName="h2" className={'m-0'}
                                          value={attributes.title}
                                          onChange={(title) => setAttributes({title})}
                                          placeholder={__('Plan name', 'attire-blocks')}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className='atbs_pricing_table_body'>
                                <RichText
                                    style={{...descrCss(attributes)}}
                                    className={'description'} tagName="p" value={attributes.description}
                                    onChange={(description) => setAttributes({description})}
                                    placeholder={__('Description...', 'attire-blocks')}/>
                                <div className="price" style={{...priceCss(attributes)}}>
                                    <RichText style={{fontSize: (attributes.priceFontSize / 2) + 'px'}}
                                              className={'symbol'}
                                              tagName="span" value={attributes.symbol}
                                              onChange={(symbol) => setAttributes({symbol})}
                                              placeholder={__('$')}/>
                                    <RichText className={'amount'}
                                              tagName="span" value={attributes.price}
                                              onChange={(price) => setAttributes({price})}
                                              placeholder={__('99.99')}/>

                                    {attributes.recurring && <RichText
                                        style={{fontSize: `${attributes.descrFontSize}${attributes.descrFontSizeUnit}`}}
                                        tagName="span" value={attributes.recurringTime}
                                        className="recurring"
                                        onChange={(value) => setAttributes({recurringTime: value})}
                                        placeholder={__('/month', 'attire-blocks')}/>}

                                </div>
                                {attributes.showFeatures && <RichText
                                    style={{...listCss(attributes)}}
                                    multiline="li"
                                    tagName="ul"
                                    className="features"
                                    onChange={(nextValues) => setAttributes({features: nextValues})}
                                    value={attributes.features}
                                    placeholder={__('Write list…', 'attire-blocks')}
                                />}

                                <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={['attire-blocks/buttons']}
                                             template={[['attire-blocks/buttons', {
                                                 buttonAlignment: 'center'
                                             }]]}
                                             templateLock="all"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Fragment>
            </Fragment>
        );
    },
    save: ({attributes, className}) => {
        //const {attributes} = props;
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <style>
                    {listIconCss(attributes)}
                </style>
                <div className={"atbs atbs-pricing-table " + className}
                     id={'atbs-pricing-table-' + attributes.blockId}>
                    <div className="plan"
                         style={{...planCss(attributes)}}>
                        {attributes.title &&
                        <div className="head" style={{...titleCss(attributes)}}>
                            <RichText.Content style={{...titleTypographyCss(attributes)}} tagName="h2" className={'m-0'}
                                              value={attributes.title}/>
                        </div>}
                        <div className='atbs_pricing_table_body'>
                            {attributes.description &&
                            <RichText.Content
                                style={{...descrCss(attributes)}}
                                className={'description'} tagName="p" value={attributes.description}/>}
                            <div className="price" style={{...priceCss(attributes)}}>
                                <RichText.Content style={{fontSize: (attributes.priceFontSize / 2) + 'px'}}
                                                  className={'symbol'} tagName="span" value={attributes.symbol}/>
                                <RichText.Content
                                    style={{
                                        color: attributes.bodyTextColor,
                                        fontSize: (attributes.priceFontSize) + 'px'
                                    }}
                                    className={'amount'}
                                    tagName="span" value={attributes.price}/>
                                {attributes.recurring && <RichText.Content
                                    style={{fontSize: `${attributes.descrFontSize}${attributes.descrFontSizeUnit}`}}
                                    className="recurring"
                                    tagName="span" value={attributes.recurringTime}/>}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {attributes.showFeatures && <RichText.Content
                            style={{...listCss(attributes)}}
                            className={'features'}
                            tagName="ul" value={attributes.features}/>}
                        <InnerBlocks.Content/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: So after saving the post, does the console show any errors? And what happens when you comment out those `useEffect()`?

Comment: no errors, just prints `console.log(props.className)` as `undefined`. Commenting out `useEffects` has no effect on the issue.

Comment: Maybe it's another block of your own, or in a plugin or the active theme - try deactivating plugins. But if you can post a link to the full code (build & source versions), perhaps I (or someone else) can help you test the block.

Comment: Here's a link to the plugin files https://www.dropbox.com/s/7kwvjquz0zxbqkc/attire-blocks.7z?dl=0

Comment: Seems like the additional classes are being modified prior to WordPress/Gutenberg saving the post, and I'd probably try disabling the internal components (e.g. `CSSEditor`) and then see if there's any of them that's causing the issue. I.e. Try your block with the bare setup (basic code) and add the internal components one at a time.

Comment: Looks like the outmost `<Fragment>` was the culprit. But I still can't figure out why! Replacing it with `<div>` fixed it.

Comment: @ShafayatAlam Please self-answer with the solution (once possible in the system), glad you found it!

Comment: @ShafayatAlam, glad you managed to fix it, but I hope my answer helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

After about an hour of trial and error, I found that the outmost `<Fragment>` was the culprit. But I still can't figure out why! Replacing it with `<div>` fixed it.

So the code looks like this now:

```
    edit: (props) => {
        const {attributes, setAttributes} = props;
        const headingBgOverlay = Util.getBgOverlay(attributes, 'heading');
        const bodyBgOverlay = Util.getBgOverlay(attributes, 'body');

        useEffect(() => {
            setAttributes({blockId: Util.guidGenerator()});
        }, []);

        useEffect(() => {
            console.log(props)
            console.log(props.className)
            console.log(attributes.className)
            setAttributes({headingBgOverlay});
            setAttributes({bodyBgOverlay});
        }, [attributes]);
        return (
                <div>
                    <style>
                        {listIconCss(attributes)}
                    </style>
                    <div className={"atbs atbs-pricing-table " + props.className}
                         id={'atbs-pricing-table-' + attributes.blockId}>
                        <div className="plan"
                             style={{...planCss(attributes)}}>
                            <div className="head" style={{...titleCss(attributes)}}>
                                <RichText style={{...titleTypographyCss(attributes)}} tagName="h2" className={'m-0'}
                                          value={attributes.title}
                                          onChange={(title) => setAttributes({title})}
                                          placeholder={__('Plan name', 'attire-blocks')}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className='atbs_pricing_table_body'>
                                <RichText
                                    style={{...descrCss(attributes)}}
                                    className={'description'} tagName="p" value={attributes.description}
                                    onChange={(description) => setAttributes({description})}
                                    placeholder={__('Description...', 'attire-blocks')}/>
                                <div className="price" style={{...priceCss(attributes)}}>
                                    <RichText style={{fontSize: (attributes.priceFontSize / 2) + 'px'}}
                                              className={'symbol'}
                                              tagName="span" value={attributes.symbol}
                                              onChange={(symbol) => setAttributes({symbol})}
                                              placeholder={__('$')}/>
                                    <RichText className={'amount'}
                                              tagName="span" value={attributes.price}
                                              onChange={(price) => setAttributes({price})}
                                              placeholder={__('99.99')}/>

                                    {attributes.recurring && <RichText
                                        style={{fontSize: `${attributes.descrFontSize}${attributes.descrFontSizeUnit}`}}
                                        tagName="span" value={attributes.recurringTime}
                                        className="recurring"
                                        onChange={(value) => setAttributes({recurringTime: value})}
                                        placeholder={__('/month', 'attire-blocks')}/>}

                                </div>
                                {attributes.showFeatures && <RichText
                                    style={{...listCss(attributes)}}
                                    multiline="li"
                                    tagName="ul"
                                    className="features"
                                    onChange={(nextValues) => setAttributes({features: nextValues})}
                                    value={attributes.features}
                                    placeholder={__('Write list…', 'attire-blocks')}
                                />}

                                <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={['attire-blocks/buttons']}
                                             template={[['attire-blocks/buttons', {
                                                 buttonAlignment: 'center'
                                             }]]}
                                             templateLock="all"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        );
    },
    save: ({attributes, className}) => {
        //const {attributes} = props;
        return (
            <div>
                <style>
                    {listIconCss(attributes)}
                </style>
                <div className={"atbs atbs-pricing-table " + className}
                     id={'atbs-pricing-table-' + attributes.blockId}>
                    <div className="plan"
                         style={{...planCss(attributes)}}>
                        {attributes.title &&
                        <div className="head" style={{...titleCss(attributes)}}>
                            <RichText.Content style={{...titleTypographyCss(attributes)}} tagName="h2" className={'m-0'}
                                              value={attributes.title}/>
                        </div>}
                        <div className='atbs_pricing_table_body'>
                            {attributes.description &&
                            <RichText.Content
                                style={{...descrCss(attributes)}}
                                className={'description'} tagName="p" value={attributes.description}/>}
                            <div className="price" style={{...priceCss(attributes)}}>
                                <RichText.Content style={{fontSize: (attributes.priceFontSize / 2) + 'px'}}
                                                  className={'symbol'} tagName="span" value={attributes.symbol}/>
                                <RichText.Content
                                    style={{
                                        color: attributes.bodyTextColor,
                                        fontSize: (attributes.priceFontSize) + 'px'
                                    }}
                                    className={'amount'}
                                    tagName="span" value={attributes.price}/>
                                {attributes.recurring && <RichText.Content
                                    style={{fontSize: `${attributes.descrFontSize}${attributes.descrFontSizeUnit}`}}
                                    className="recurring"
                                    tagName="span" value={attributes.recurringTime}/>}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {attributes.showFeatures && <RichText.Content
                            style={{...listCss(attributes)}}
                            className={'features'}
                            tagName="ul" value={attributes.features}/>}
                        <InnerBlocks.Content/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this has to do with some of the block editor's magic, that tries to add the correct block/variant/etc. classes to the root element. If there is no root element (ie a Fragment), it seems to fail right now. Did you consider opening an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues)?

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like the outmost `<Fragment>` was the culprit. But I still can't
> figure out why! Replacing it with `<div>` fixed it.

If you're on **WordPress 5.6.0**, you don't need to replace the `<Fragment>` with `<div>`. :)

And that's because WordPress 5.6.0 actually came with [block API version 2](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/18/block-api-version-2/) which introduced a new hook named `useBlockProps` that should be used in a [block's `edit()` and `save()` functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/) — you can read more on the link I provided, but basically, with `useBlockProps`, you'd be able to use `Fragment` as the outmost wrapper.

Working example based on the one [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/introducing-attributes-and-editable-fields/):

```js
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { useBlockProps, RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';

registerBlockType( 'my-plugin/foo-block', {
    // Required; use the block API version 2
    apiVersion: 2,

    title: 'Foo Block',
    category: 'design',

    attributes: {
        content: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: 'p',
        },
    },

    // In edit(), use useBlockProps()
    edit: ( props ) => {
        const { attributes: { content }, setAttributes, className } = props;
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();

        const onChangeContent = ( newContent ) => {
            setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
        };

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className={ blockProps.className }>
                    <RichText
                        { ...blockProps }
                        tagName="p"
                        onChange={ onChangeContent }
                        value={ content }
                    />
                    <p>{ 'Back-end: ' + blockProps.className }</p>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    },

    // In save(), use useBlockProps.save()
    save: ( props ) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className={ blockProps.className }>
                    <RichText.Content
                        { ...blockProps }
                        tagName="p"
                        value={ props.attributes.content }
                    />
                    <p>{ 'Front-end: ' + blockProps.className }</p>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    },
} );
```

So as you can see above, to get the additional CSS class(es) ( and other/auto-generated CSS class(es) ), I used `blockProps.className` and not `props.className` which gave us `undefined`.